# Android email population

Tags: android, string, email

I am trying to create an app that has a button to "submit" an email. I have 2 lists that have items in them that I need to convert to strings and then append them onto the body of the email.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "ToAddress@gmail.com" } );
String temp = "";
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Rob Won!!!" );
for( int a = 0; a < i; a++) {
    temp += Item.get(a).toString() + "\t\t" + Prices.get(a).toString() + "\n";
}
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, temp );
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");


//hideKeyboard();
PeaBerryTeaActivity.this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Item is a list of "products" as strings, and Prices is a list of well "prices" also listed as strings. The problem I am having is that in the ForLoop I am creating the message body, but when the intent is started the email does not have anything listed in the body and just a blinking cursor.